# kubernetes ceph Storage Classes for Dynamic Provisioning executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I am running local ceph (version 10.2.7) and kubernetes v1.6.5 in separate cluster. Using PV and PVM Claim I was about mount the rbd device to the pod.

When I configure to use ceph Storage Classes for Dynamic Provisioning. its giving the below error for pvclaim.

```
E0623 00:22:30.520160       1 rbd.go:317] rbd: create volume failed, err: failed to create rbd image: executable file not found in $PATH, command output:
W0623 00:22:45.513291       1 rbd_util.go:364] failed to create rbd image, output
E0623 00:22:45.513308       1 rbd.go:317] rbd: create volume failed, err: failed to create rbd image: executable file not found in $PATH, command output:
W0623 00:22:45.516768       1 rbd_util.go:364] failed to create rbd image, output
E0623 00:22:45.516830       1 rbd.go:317] rbd: create volume failed, err: failed to create rbd image: executable file not found in $PATH, command output:
```

I have installed ceph comman package on all the kuberernets cluster nodes. all the node running centos 7 OS.

How can I fix this error message?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1):

Well, the internal `kubernetes.io/rbd` does not work, which is known for very long time and eg. discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/85454).

One should use an external provisionier like the one mentioned [here](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/rbd-kubernetes/).

Answer (score 0):

Kubelet is trying to run `rbd create ...`.
The `rbd` command needs to be in the PATH of the kubelet binary.
Kubelet usually runs as root.  Check if you can run rbd create as root.  If not, add it to root's path, or to the environment of whatever script (systemd?) that is starting Kubelet.

Comment: I check its there. [root@cm-02 ~]# ls -l /usr/bin/rbd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4071088 Apr 10 08:39 /usr/bin/rbd

Answer (score 0):

You need define a new provisioner rbd-provisioner. Ref [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38923).